# Adding name attribute results in ID value becoming property of the document object in IE and Opera?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, opera

Consider this HTML source code:

```
<form id="foo1" name="x"> Form 1 </form>
<form id="foo2"> Form 2 </form>
```

As you can see, we define two FORM elements.

In Chrome, Safari and Firefox, both `document.foo1` and `document.foo2` return `undefined`.

However, in IE and Opera, `document.foo1` returns a reference to the corresponding FORM element, whereas `document.foo2` returns `undefined`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zrmEm/2/

So, the first form does have its ID-named property in the document object, and the second form doesn't. And this difference is the result of adding the `name` attribute to the first form.

Now, where's the logic in that? Is this a known behavior?

Comment: You should simply ignore what global variables these browsers do and don't make for you because you shouldn't use them.  They aren't standard.  Use `document.getElementById()` to get a DOM reference to an object with an id.  The reason it's different from one browser to the next is that it's not defined by a standard.

Comment: Just don't let Google know about it or they'll add it to the next version of Chrome. I mean they've already got `document.all` and `window.event` for goodness sake. Seems that they secretly want to be IE!

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ Too late for that. Chrome (and other browsers) do add window and document properties "all over the place". For instance, for the above HTML code, Chrome will create 3 global properties: `window.foo1`, `window.foo2` and `window.x`, and one document property: `document.x` (all those are references to the forms). This global namespace pollution is a bit disturbing to say at least but all browsers except Firefox (!!) do it. **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/c4tTw/

Comment: Not only that- opera and IE (even #10) add everything with an id to the window object. alert(elementid) returns a reference to that object as if wer a global var. And you were so careful to not pollute the global namespace...

Comment: The theme of the WHAT WG IRC channel comes to mind: "Please leave your sense of logic at the door, thanks.". No, there is no logic to this. Opera has decided to do it (for now) because we found a page depending on it. We might decide to stop doing this in the near future if we think we can get away with it on the web. So please help us drop it - don't write any script that depends on this quirk :).

Answer (score 1):

In all browsers, the value of a form's *name* attribute is added as a property of the document object, and also as a property of the *document.forms* [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064).

If you are using ids, the values are added only as properties of the *forms* collection.

IE was always confused about name and id attributes. In IE (version 8 tested), the id is added a property of the document **only** if there is also a name for that form (it might be the same or different to the id).

So if you always use *document.forms['name-or-id']* then life is sweet. As long as you don't have forms with names that are the same as other forms with ids, then all bets are off.

Comment: eh... Your answer is accurate as far as I can tell and you articulated it better than I did mine.  So I've just deleted mine :P

Comment: Just to add to that, it's important to note that `id`s and `name`s reside in the same namespace. In cases where you have a unique element that *should* have a `name` attribute, it's wise to have the `id` and `name` match.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a quirk that Microsoft introduced way back in the dark days of the browser wars. (circa IE4)

The end result is that in IE, forms would be added as variables to the document scope, so that you could reference them as `document.form1`.

This was non-standard, but that didn't really seem to matter back then (at least not to the browser vendors).

Many of the non-standard features that were added at the time to one browser or another ended up being implemented by the others, became de-facto standards, and eventually ended up as official standards.

This particular feature, however, did not. It remains non-standard.

Microsoft have retained most of their old non-standard functionality even in newer versions of their browser, in an effort to retain backward compatibility for old code (many corporate intranets were written by Microsoft-trained 'experts', and use these features, so they need to keep them, otherwise no-one will ever upgrade past IE6).

Back in those days, Opera was the young pretender in the browser world. It was updated often, had innovative features, and ran much quicker than the competition. They were doing back then for the browser world what Chrome has been doing more recently.

However because of the escalating standards war, the only way Opera could compete was by being compatible, and they went to great lengths to reverse-engineer all the features (and even in some cases the bugs) in IE so that sites written for IE would also work in Opera.

This was clearly one of those features, and this is why IE and Opera both share the same quirk today.

The other browsers on the market today do not have the same history. Firefox is ultimately derived from Netscape Navigator, so while it may have its own quirks dating back to those days, but it won't share IE's. And the webkit browsers have a much more recent provenance (it is derived from the KDE Project's KHTML engine), so again it never had the history where it was trying to emulate IE's quirks.